# How can I get an accurate character count when using crayon-formatted strings?

Tags: r, crayon

`crayon` is a package for adding color to printed output, e.g.

```
library(crayon)
message(red('blue'), green('green'), blue('red'))
```

[image: sample colored text]

However, `nchar` used on its output is wrong:

```
# should be 4 characters
nchar(red('1234'))
# [1] 14
```

I tried all the different `type=` options for `nchar`, to no avail -- how can I get R to tell me the correct number of characters in this string (4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the output of `red` is just a plain string:

```
r = red('1234')
dput(r)
# "\033[31m1234\033[39m"
class(r)
# [1] "character"
```

The garbled-looking parts (`\033[31m` and `\033[39m`) are what are known as [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) -- you can think of it here as signalling "start red" and "stop red". While the program that converts the character object into printed characters in your terminal is aware of and translates these, `nchar` is not. `nchar` in fact sees 14 characters:

```
strsplit(r, NULL)[[1L]]
#  [1] "\033" "["    "3"    "1"    "m"    "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "\033" "["   
# [12] "3"    "9"    "m"
```

To get the 4 we're after, `crayon` provides a helper function: `col_nchar` which first applies `strip_style` to get rid of the ANSI markup, then runs plain `nchar`:

```
strip_style(r)
# [1] "1234"
col_nchar(r)
# [1] 4
```

So you can either do `nchar(strip_style(x))` yourself if you find that more readable, or use `col_nchar`.